# Trouble with REST/jersey and JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jersey-1.0

I have an exception with JSON in a REST / jersey.

I got `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class de.xxx, and Java type class de.xxx, and MIME media type application/json was not found`

And i got the message:

```
ERROR ContainerResponse - The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONWithPaddingProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
```

The configuration seems to be OK. I have 'jersey-json' in my dependencies too.

Does anyone have an idea: what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use genson lib to serialize and deserialize your class to json.

```
Genson genson = new Genson();
YourClass obj = genson.deserialize(json.toString(), YourClass.class);
String strJson = genson.serialize(obj);
```

With this way, you can return in entity a POJO.

The libs i normaly use to work with ret/jersey are this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It's fine. But you must itself into your code test the required mimetype. Like:
'if(xml){
    do something..
else(json){
    make genson
}'

jersey-json make it automatically.

Comment: I defined the mime type in the method with an annotation. You want to do it automatically?

Comment: I use annotations too. My code:
`@GET
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
 public Response listClusters(@QueryParam(ClusterFilter.NODE) String node,....`

Comment: What a confusion! 
Why you dont try to make a private method that return a POJO and then make two methods (one for xml and other for Json) that only calls the private method and return the object in the correct way?

Comment: It's one possibility. I did it with jersey-json. It's smarter and worked with old versions.

Comment: If you like my answer, please approve and vote them.
tks

Comment: @Robert if you have genson in the classpath it will automatically do the mapping for mime type json for you. No need to do anything special

Answer (score 0):

Register the JacksonFeature.class to the list of providers in the Resource COnfig or Application type. once after you have the jersey jackson library in your class path.